# Algorithm to add new point to a polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d

In the application I am developing I have  polygons as show in the picture

[image]

My data structure is double-linked list as follows.

```
RzCurve {
   RzNode *head;
};


RzNode{
      double x;
      double y;
      RzNode *next;
      RzNode *prev;
}
```

I want to implement an algorithm which allows user to add a new Node by clicking mouse.

Any tips on this?

Regards,
umanga

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably go through all line segments, calculate the [distance of the point to the line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) segment, and insert the point between the end points of the line segment with the shortest distance to the new point. Further I would only consider line segments where the line through the new point and perpendicular to the line through the end points of the line segment intersects the line segment.

Comment: Considering the "Further" part of that reduces the complexity of the distance of point to line - you won't have to consider distance from point to end-points. This *might* also give results equivalent to answer from Mau but simpler to implement.

Answer (score 1):

*I* would go though all pairs of corners, compute the bisector to the 2 angles. If the clicked point falls into the semi-plane defined by the 2 bisectors and the segment between the 2 angles, then your point must be added to the current segment (i.e. the new point gets connected to the 2 corners under exam).

You have to be careful with concave polygons. If the 2 bisectors intersect outside the polygon, the point must be added to the current segment only if it falls inside the triangle defined by bisectors and segment.

Example:

[alt text http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/2098/134073347.png](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/2098/134073347.png)

Comment: Mau , is there a link to an image ? seems its invalid.